# В чем ошибка тут?

Tags: java

```
public class Interval {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите число в диапазоне 0-100: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int interval;
        interval = in.nextInt();

        if (interval <= -1);
        {

            System.out.println("Вы ввели число в недопустимом диапазоне");
        }
        if (interval >= 101)
        {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели число в недопустимом диапазоне");
        }

        if (interval >= 0);
        {
            if (interval <= 14)
            {
                System.out.println("Число в диапазоне от 0 до 15");
            }
        }

        if (interval >= 15);
        {
            if (interval <= 35)
            {
                System.out.println("Число в диапазоне от 15 до 35");
            }
        }
        if (interval >= 36);
        {
            if (interval <= 50)
            {
                System.out.println("Число в диапазоне от 36 до 50");
            }
        }
        if (interval >= 50);
        {
            if (interval <= 100)
            {
                System.out.println("Число в диапазоне от 50 до 100");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Если ввести 101 в interval Сработает условие и на <= -1 и на >=101. Также если ввести 36 сработает и "от 36 до 50" и "от 50 до 100".
Подскажите в чем дело, где сделал ошибку?

Answer (score 4):

Мешают точки с запятыми после условий, и не хватает `else`:

```
    if (interval <= -1 || interval >= 101)
    {
        System.out.println("Вы ввели число в недопустимом диапазоне");
    }
    else if (interval >= 0 && interval <= 14)
    {
        System.out.println("Число в диапазоне от 0 до 14");
    }
    else if ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Честно, приведенный пример не самый "хороший" способ решения. Попробуй в следующий раз использовать условие `else if (condition) {..}`. Грубо говоря:

`Если` (число больше нуля `или`[|| - две палки вниз] меньше нуля) {
 ответ:..
} `В ином случае если` (Число меньше 15) {..}

Пример диаграммы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как мы определили изначально, что число находится между 0 и 100, далее просто проверяем отрезки по его максимальному диапазону - < 15; < 35; < 50;
Предположим, что проверяем число `45`. Оно:
`(0 > 45 || 45 > 100)` - ложь, переходим в пункт `else`
`(45 < 15)` - ложь, переходим в пункт `else`
`(45 < 35)` - ложь, переходим в пункт `else`
`(45 < 50)` - истина, выводим `Число в диапазоне от 36 до 50` и завершаем ДАННОЕ дерево из if и else условий.

Финальная программа:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Interval {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите число в диапазоне 0-100: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int interval = in.nextInt();

        if (interval < 0 || interval > 100)
        {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели число в недопустимом диапазоне");
        } else if (interval < 15)
        {
          System.out.println("Число в диапазоне от 0 до 15");
        } else if (interval < 35)
        {
          System.out.println("Число в диапазоне от 15 до 35");
        } else if(interval < 50)
        {
          System.out.println("Число в диапазоне от 36 до 50");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Число в диапазоне от 50 до 100");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Благодарю!

Comment: @Григорий Лайкни, если он подошел тебе... Старался помочь с, возможно незнакомой тебе, темой